# Unicode issue: certain characters not displaying

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, kana

I am having some issues in trying to get certain unicode characters to show up when trying to type. It seems that no matter what I do I can't get them to appear outside of certain specific places.

The two characters that I am trying to get show up are:

and

The Japanese archaic katakana e and Japanese archaic hiragana ye. In unicode they are in the Kana Supplement block.

You can find them here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kana_Supplement

I can't seem to get these characters to show up outside of these instances:

- In firefox when hardware acceleration disabled (and only when it is disabled)
- This webpage: http://www.akenotsuki.com/eyeben/font/unicode.html

The second webpage works even when hardware acceleration in firefox is enabled.

Here's what I've tried to do to resolve the issue:

- Installing & reinstalling proper fonts
- Rebooting the computer
- Clearing the font cache
- Setting the system locale to Japanese (hey, it was worth a shot)

None of which has worked. Can someone please help me? I want to get this to resolve itself especially because I want to be able to use this in Photoshop.

Comment: Those characters are part of the range that don't fit in a single UTF-16 entity. Programs may treat them differently than other characters, but that should be considered a bug in the application. Another problem range that comes up often is the [emoticons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticons_%28Unicode_block%29).

Comment: Ah, so is it a simple compatibility issue that I can't do much else to solve?